# Why printf repeats previous value when printing integer in float tag

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, output, printf

I ran some code in C, and I ran into an interesting occurance when printing integers in float place.
This is the code:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%f\n",5);
    printf("%f\n",5.5);
    printf("%f",5);

    return 0;
}
```

`The output is:`0.000000
5.500000
5.500000`

My question is why it repeats the value? Specifically how it works on low level

I thought it might be connected to the stack.

Comment: Undefined behavior.  The "low level" explanation will depend on the specific platform, compiler, optimization options, surrounding code, etc, etc.

Comment: You will have to rework your post with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Otherwise it looks like the shown code cannot possibly create the output you show.

Comment: But on some platforms, floating-point arguments are passed in a separate type of register than integer arguments.  So `printf("%f", 5)` may ignore the 5 completely and print whatever happens to be in the relevant floating-point register.  Maybe it's 0 the first time.  And maybe the third time, your value `5.5` is still in that register because nothing happened to overwrite it yet.  I hope it goes without saying that there is no guarantee that this or anything like it will always happen.

Comment: Lesson: Do not ignore the standard.

Comment: Enable warnings and treat warnings as errors. You would have gotten something like: `error: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Werror=format=]` for the 1st and 2rd call to `printf`.